# How to control which option is selected in a <select> control?

Tags: html, html-select

What I tried is by adding `selected`, but this is not working:

```
<select>
 <option value="-1" selected>--</option>
 <option value="0">femail</option>
 <option value="1">male</option>
</select>
```

Comment: not to be nit picky, but it is spelled female btw...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several browsers will save your current selection when you reload the page.  Try clearing your browsers cache and reloading the page (shift + f5).  What you have above should be correct.

Answer (score 3):

Try `selected="selected"`